# Espresso - Properly clear Activities saved instance states

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am writing espresso tests for my app and having difficulties clearing the app state, state gets saved and this affects other tests and brings flakiness to them.

I use intent rule for starting my activity:

```
    @Rule
    public final IntentsTestRule<MainActivity> mIntentsTestRule = newIntentsTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, true, false);
```

My setUp clears everything that I have access to: db, sharedPrefs, custom volatile config.

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
     mSharedPrefManager.clear();
     mAppConfig.clear();
     mDatabasePersister.deleteDatabase();
    }
```

Sadly I have issues with activity saved instance state, this brings **flakiness** to my tests since previous states are retained.

Is there a way to *clear the saved instance states* programmatically for each activity start?

Comment: Did you try to finish your activity after each test? Instance state should not be stored for explicit finished activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by a memory leak, so the activity was kept without properly clearing it, thanks for the effort, after resolving the leak espresso ran fine.